# Android App Insights logging in debug mode

Tags: android, azure, azure-application-insights

I just setup app insights on my android app but I am not seeing any telemetry make it to the azure dashboard. Does anybody know if you have to do anything special in the setup to make it work when debugging? The documentation doesn't specify anything that would make me think it won't send when in debug mode but I put in the right instrumentation key and I am getting nothing.

As one of the answers mentioned, I checked the logcat after enabling developer mode. and here is what I found:

> W/com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logging Sender: Couldn't send data
>   with IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve
>   host "dc.services.visualstudio.com": No address associated with
>   hostname

and this...

> I/com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logging Sender: Persisting because
>   of IOException: :We're probably offline =)

and this...

> I/com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logging Channel: enqueued
>   telemetry:Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PageView

Comment: Maybe you have to wait a few minutes/hours?

Comment: What about the play store analitics? Do you see any errors there that should be on Azure?

Comment: Maybe the app needs the Wi-FI/Internet permission... did you took a look at the `adb logcat` output?

Comment: I followed the instructions and added the two uses-permissions they wanted. android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing more needed to enable events while debugging. Can you please enable developer mode using

```
ApplicationInsights.setDeveloperMode(true);
```

and look for log statements in logcat that say you are successfully sending data?
If your problem persists, please shoot me an email via AppInsights-Android@microsoft.com.

By the way, there was a 1.0-beta.9 release the other day, are you already using it?

Comment: I emailed you but have not received a response. My android apps still do not show up in Azure App Insights. :(

Comment: I checked log cat and I'm getting this: W/com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logging Sender: Couldn't send data with IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "dc.services.visualstudio.com": No address associated with hostname